# How to split unlabeled data into train and test set using train_test_split?

Tags: python, train-test-split

I am new in data sicence und actually try to build my first model.
I am confuse about the correct way to use the split function. Most of documentations recommend the following approach (where X=data und Y= label):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```

I have a dataset without label (X=data), and want to build a model based on it to predict anomalies. That means, I can actually split my dataset only in 2 (portion: X_train and X_test). But I am not sure if this is the correct for my dataset and would like to know how should I proceed to get y. Thank you advance for your support

Comment: Are u doing unsupervised learning? I tot that you might want to explore clustering or other form of unsupervised learning.....

Comment: share the dataset, the columns and rows ..etc

Comment: I am doing unsupervised learning. A look of the dataset. Thks                                      POSDAT|AEDAT|DOCNR|WAERS|KTOSL|BELNR|HKONT|DMBTR|WRBTR 
01.01.1994|09.01.1994|A1|C3       |C31    |C9        |C92      | 280979.60 | 0.00
02.01.1994|NaN      |A2 | C1       | C76    |A1 |B2      |129856.53| 243343.00
03.01.1994|NaN |A3 |C1       |C20   |A1 |B3      |957463.97 |3183838.41

Answer (score 0):

You can see the example in the [link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html). The function can work on one variable also

> train_test_split(y, shuffle=False)

In your case, the answer will be

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(X, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
```